# Image slicing in python showing attribute error

Tags: python, image-slicer

```
import image_slicer
image_slicer.slice('image_name',16)
```

I am trying to slice an image into 16 parts in python. And my code is the above one.

This same code perfectly worked fine before (I have image_slicer version 0.3.0) but this time this is throwing an error 'module 'image_slicer' has no attribute 'slice''. I have also checked the attributes of this module and I am very confused now. Moreover, I am keeping the code in the same folder of the image and so everything else should be fine. What can I do ? Even tried uninstalling 0.3.0 version and installing 0.2.0 and still the same error.

Comment: What is the name of the python module your code is in? Is it `image_slicer.py`, by any chance?

Comment: @dspencer the name of my python code file was image_slicer.py . Can that be an issue?

Comment: @dspencer I just renamed the file and it worked thanks so much :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of your python module is `image_slicer.py`. Therefore, when you `import image_slicer`, your current module is found before the installed `image_slicer` package. Since your module does not define `slice`, `AttributeError` is raised.

To avoid these problems, you should ensure that your module names do not conflict with packages.